# Convert array of objects to array of arrays (by attribute)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, reduce

I want transform my array to array of arrays by attribute "icon".

```
const array = [
  { icon: true }, 
  { icon: false },
  { icon: false }, 
  { icon: true }, 
  { icon: false }
]
```

I need:

```
[[{icon: true}, {icon: false}, {icon: false}], [{{icon: true}, {icon: false}}]]
```

Attribute `icon === true` is a sign of the beginning of the formation of a new array.

I think you should use the function reduce.

`array.reduce((result, item, index) => { ... }, [])`

How best to write a transformation? Thanks!

Comment: please add what **you** have tried.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.reduce()` method as follow:

```js
const data = [{ icon: true }, { icon: false }, { icon: false }, { icon: true }, { icon: false }]

const result = data.reduce((r, c) => {
  if(c.icon === true)
    r.push([c]);
  else
    r[Math.max(r.length - 1, 0)].push(c);
    
  return r;
},[]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks! It is perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `while` *loop*.

```js
const array = [{ icon: true }, { icon: false }, { icon: false }, { icon: true }, { icon: false }]
i = 0;
result = [];
aux = [];
while(i <  array.length){
   if(array[i].icon){
     if(aux.length !== 0){
        result.push(aux);
        aux = [array[i]];
     }
     else
        aux.push(array[i]);
   }
   else
     aux.push(array[i]);
   i++;
}
result.push(aux);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a closure over the array for inserting. This prevents to look up the last item in the array.

```js
const
    data = [{ icon: true }, { icon: false }, { icon: false }, { icon: true }, { icon: false }],
    result = data.reduce((a => (r, o) => {
        if (o.icon) r.push(a = []);
        a.push(o);
        return r;
    })(), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array = [
  { icon: true },
  { icon: false },
  { icon: false },
  { icon: true },
  { icon: false }
];

console.log(grouper(array));

function grouper(array) {
  return array.reduce((acc, next) => {
    const entry = [next];

    if (next.icon) return acc.concat([entry]);
    const beforeNextCollection = acc.slice(0, acc.length - 1);

    const nextCollection = acc[acc.length - 1];
    const updatedCollection = nextCollection.concat(entry);

    return beforeNextCollection.concat([updatedCollection]);
  }, []);
}
```